# How to use "." in LIKE query?

Tags: t-sql, sql-like

When i use `.` operator in `LIKE` operator query is not selecting any of the records.

**My query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM XSP_AssetList_V 
WHERE AccountID = '5d6b1eab-1697-de11-a2d1-00505617006d'
AND PrinterSerialNumber
LIKE '%13.12%'
```

How to use `.` in `LIKE`?

Comment: Please post the values of the record which in your opinion should be selected.

Comment: i have an ip address in the record whose value is 13.121.238.11

how do i select the records whose value is  13.121.238.11
  using sql query

Comment: IP address query works fine in one of my random tables like you have it.  Are you sure it's not your account# throwing off the expected results?

Comment: When i write the query without " . " it is working fine but when i say 13.121 it is not dispalying any records.

SELECT * FROM XSP_AssetList_V  WHERE AccountID = '5d6b1eab-1697-de11-a2d1-00505617006d'  AND PrinterSerialNumber LIKE '%13%'

Answer (score 4):

In SQL, the single character wildcard is "_"  not "."

```
LIKE '%13_12%'
```

- % match any string of zero or more characters.
- _ match any single character.
- [ ] match any single character within the specified range (for example, [a-f]) or set (for example, [abcdef]).
- [^] match any single character not within the specified range (for example, [^a - f]) or set (for example, [^abcdef]).

Comment: I think the OP is not looking for a single-character wildcard. It's asking why the actual '.' character isn't matching where it should.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing should work, maybe your AccountID is incorrect or the combination of both doesn't return anything

```
create table #test(ip varchar(16))
insert #test values ('13.121.238.11')
insert #test values ('13.124.254.128')
insert #test values ('127.0.0.1')

select * from #test where ip like '%13.12%'
```

Comment: combination of both works 
SELECT * FROM XSP_AssetList_V  WHERE AccountID = '5d6b1eab-1697-de11-a2d1-00505617006d'  AND PrinterSerialNumber LIKE '%13%'  
 will display records
but this does not display recoreds
SELECT * FROM XSP_AssetList_V  WHERE AccountID = '5d6b1eab-1697-de11-a2d1-00505617006d'  AND PrinterSerialNumber LIKE '%13.12%'